# pass function returning void * as argument

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, function-pointers, void-pointers

I wanted to pass a function taking as argument and returning a `void *` to another function.
Right now i have the following code:

```
MyClass *MyClass::bind(std::function<void*(void *)> fun) {
    this->value = fun(this->value);
    return this;
}
```

`value` is a `void *` variable inside `MyClass`, i can't figure out how to pass a function to my function `bind`.
When i try to pass it the name of a function like this

```
auto *class = new MyClass();
class->bind(fooFunction);
```

i get the error

```
no viable conversion from '<overloaded function type>' to 'std::function<void *(void *)>'
```

Is there any way to achieve what i want with this code or does an easier approach exist?

Comment: Your problem is not in the code shown, but rather in code you chose not to show.  Type a [MCVE] that reproduces the error and otherwise compiles yet is minimal and share that.  Your variable names are illegal, so your pseudo-code cannot be code for completely unrelated reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more than one overload of `fooFunction`.

Use a function name with only one overload (that matches the signature).

Alternatively, wrap it in a lambda:

```
auto *bob = new MyClass();
bob->bind([](void*ptr)->void*{return fooFunction(ptr);});
```

and rely on stateless lambda implicit cast to function pointer.

Comment: yeah i wrote the wrong type in the function definition so i had two functions with the same name in the code. I have another question but i'll make a new question with more details in the future.